# Automatically add a subclass to registry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For each subclass of the `BaseStrategy` being declared, I want to add them to the `BaseStrategy.strategies` array to be used later. What I can do is add class method `BaseStrategy.register_strategy` and call it in each subclass. But this would be error prone. Instead, I want `BaseStrategy.register_strategy` automatically invoked if a new subclass of `BaseStrategy` being declared. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inherited` hook:

```
class BaseStrategy
  class << self
    def inherited(klass)
      register_strategy(klass)
    end

    def register_strategy(strategy)
      puts "Adding strategy #{strategy}"
    end
  end
end

class Foo < BaseStrategy
end
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for